# extend uikit plugin - add code to a function

Tags: jquery-plugins, uikit, accordion

I'm using the accordion component of uikit and I'm trying to extend the plugin ... this is what I wrote

```
UIkit.on('beforeready.uk.dom', function () {
    $.extend(UIkit.components.accordion.prototype, {
        init: function () { 


        }
    });
```

and this is the init code that is changing:

```
init: function() {

            var $this = this;

            this.element.on('click.uikit.accordion', this.options.toggle, function(e) {

                e.preventDefault();

                $this.toggleItem(UI.$(this).data('wrapper'), $this.options.animate, $this.options.collapse);
            });

            this.update();

            if (this.options.showfirst) {
                this.toggleItem(this.toggle.eq(0).data('wrapper'), false, false);
            }
        },
```

as you can see with this code I can override the init function ...however I want to keep the existing init function and add some code in it....is it possible to do so?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi , you've found an answer? I have the same problem @sara.y

Comment: @maliness ,No unfortunately not...but I try to post an answer if I managed to find one

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have found a solution, I used angularJs and animation css to reproduce the effect of the uikit accordion. For me it's ok and quick